# Wildcard Regular Expression to Next Space

Tags: java, regex, wildcard

I am facing a moment of confusion and wondering if what I am doing can be done within Regex.

I have tried many regular expresssion but kept failing at creating the correct one.

I am looking to write a regular expression using a wildcard.

An example would be:

Text to search shown below

> "Using a regular expression to validate an email address"

Regex Requirements
val*

This would return "validate"

Is this possible within regex?

I basicly want to search for "partofakeyword*tonextspacebreak"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem

Comment: `(val.*)\s` matches validate. Is this what you want? I afraid I don't understand your question, please elaborate more.

Comment: @MarounMaroun no, this matches `validate an email`. The correct regex would be `val\S*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\S` means *non-whitespace character*. It's a shorthand for `[^\s]`.

Therefore `\S*` means *a sequence of non-whitespace characters*.

So the regex you're looking for is `val\S*`.

Comment: I doubt that's _really_ what LmC wanted though (even if it's technically what was asked), since this would also match things like punctuation.

Comment: @Tom yes, I was unsure. That's why I provided this answer in addition to yours to let the asker decide what he really needs.

Answer (score 2):

`val\w*`

Explanation: `\w` means "any word character" (letters, numbers, underscore), and `*` means "0 or more".

Comment: In java `\w` is ASCII only. I'd rather use `\p{L}` or `[\p{L}\p{N}]` as a workaround if you want to match text. These handle Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure of the question but like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
        "Using a regular expression to validate an email address"
            .replaceAll(".*(val[^\\s]*)\\s.*", "$1")
    );
}
```